# Modify Command Line Arguments

Tags: c++, winapi, command-line

I have a Win32 C++ application and I need to modify the command line arguments in the application. Specifically, I want to edit the command line arguments in such a way that `GetCommandLineW()` returns my new arguments.

Believe it or not, this works (since we have a non-const pointer to the character array):

```
LPTSTR args = GetCommandLineW();
LPTSTR new_args = L"foo --bar=baz";
wmemcpy(args, new_args, lstrlenW(new_args));

// ...
LPTSTR args2 = GetGommentLineW(); // <- equals "foo --bar=baz"
```

But I don't know how long much memory Windows allocates for the `LPTSTR` provided by `GetCommandLineW()`.

Is there another way to do this? Or does anyone know if there is a predictable amount of memory allocated for the command line arguments?

Comment: I would argue that this is undefined behavior. You're lucky it works in this case, but it shouldn't be counted on. Instead you probably need to re-design your program, either so it doesn't have to modify the arguments, or that you store the arguments in your own variable and change only that.

Comment: There is a specific use case where I am tying into a very large body of existing code, that uses command line arguments deep within it. Certainly it is simplest to just modify the command line arguments if such a thing can be made reliable. Hence the question.

Comment: Whatever `GetGommentLineW` is we do not know. Regardless, it bears some insanity to modify the contents `GetCommandLineW` returns from the same process that calls `GetCommandLineW`. Why not simply alter that part of the source code that calls `GetCommandLineW` instead of 'patching' the API call?

Comment: Hmm, just use `#define GetCommandLineW`. It's about as safe as what you're doing now.

Comment: [Why does GetCommandLine give me a corrupted command line?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100113-00/?p=15293)

Answer (score 6):

`GetCommandLineW()` does not allocate any memory.  It simply returns a pointer to a buffer that is allocated by the OS in the process's [`PEB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706.aspx) structure when the process is created.  That buffer exists for the lifetime of the process.

Comment: So the lifetime issue is not a problem. Then the OP will just have to worry about potential buffer overflows.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest and safest way to modify what that function returns is to modify the function. Install a detour so that any calls to the function from inside your process are re-routed to a function that you provide.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to inspect on PEB structure, where the `CommandLine` (unicode) string lies.

On my machine, under both x86 and x64 `CommandLine` is right after `ImagePathName`, so I think there won't be more space for the former one either. Writing a longer string to that buffer does might cause an overflow.

```
#include <winnt.h>
#include <winternl.h>


int main()
{
    // Thread Environment Block (TEB)
#if defined(_M_X64) // x64
    PTEB tebPtr = (PTEB)__readgsqword((DWORD) & (*(NT_TIB*)NULL).Self);
#else // x86
    PTEB tebPtr = (PTEB)__readfsdword((DWORD) & (*(NT_TIB*)NULL).Self);
#endif
    // Process Environment Block (PEB)
    PPEB pebPtr = tebPtr->ProcessEnvironmentBlock;
    PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ppPtr = pebPtr->ProcessParameters;

    printf("ImagePathName:\tlen=%d maxlen=%d ptr=%p\n", ppPtr->ImagePathName.Length, ppPtr->ImagePathName.MaximumLength, ppPtr->ImagePathName.Buffer);
    printf("CommandLine:\tlen=%d maxlen=%d ptr=%p\n", ppPtr->CommandLine.Length, ppPtr->CommandLine.MaximumLength, ppPtr->CommandLine.Buffer);
    printf("GetCommandLineA:\tptr=%p\n", GetCommandLineA());
    printf("GetCommandLineW:\tptr=%p\n", GetCommandLineW());
    printf("Addr Delta between CommandLine and ImagePathName: %d\n", (char*)ppPtr->CommandLine.Buffer - (char*)ppPtr->ImagePathName.Buffer);
}
```