# Writing to command line arguments

Tags: c, winapi, command-line

Is it safe (not causing undefined behavior) to overwrite the command line string that is returned from calling the `GetCommandLine` function?

```
*(GetCommandLineW() + 1) = L'x'; // should be fine, right?
```

I'm not sure whether to treat the returned string as a string literal as the assigned protection attributes of the corresponding memory pages seem to differentiate.

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbiMemPage;

VirtualQuery(GetCommandLineW(), &mbiMemPage,
             sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)); // mbiMemPage.Protect = PAGE_READWRITE

VirtualQuery(L"some string", &mbiMemPage,
             sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)); // mbiMemPage.Protect = PAGE_EXECUTE_READ
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125801/modify-command-line-arguments

Comment: The documentation offers no reason for you to be able to believe that this can safely be modified. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I need to retrieve a specific argument from a list of arguments and I'm looking for a way to do so without having to copy the entire contents of the argument to another buffer.

Comment: Nothing there suggests any need to modify the contents. Almost certainly you have hit upon the wrong solution to your problem.

Comment: Why is the documentation not very clear and strict about avoiding to write to the returned string? MSDN usually isn't shy about overstating the obvious. I thought I overlooked something and just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The return type is not const, it is conceivable that MS wants to allow unix style "status updates".

Comment: It's not MSDN's job to list all the possible things that you might want to do, that you aren't allowed to do. Such a list is infinite. It just tells you what they contractually state can be done. You have the wrong solution.

Comment: @Anders The return type is not `const` for historical reasons. This API has been around for a very very long time.

Comment: Why don't you call [CommandLineToArgvW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx) then? Or use the [__wargv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv) global variable, pre-populated by the CRT's startup code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetCommandLineW` returns a pointer to a string stored in the PEB but that is a implementation detail. It is safe to modify the string on every released version of Windows NT but that does not mean that it will stay like that forever. However, the return type is LPTSTR and not LPCTSTR so I find it unlikely that it will be stored in a read-only page in the future.

It is really up to you if you want to risk it. Just keep in mind that you cannot exceed the initial string length and somebody could rename your application to "x.exe" and run it simply as "x" leaving you only two characters to play with.

If you just want to parse and extract a parameter you can use [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx).